# st_make_grid() not using correct map units

Tags: r, maps, r-sf

Let me start by saying I've seen the other thread on a similar question, and even after replicating the nc maps problem they use, I'm still running into a problem with my own code.

I'm trying to create a map with 50km square grids imposed over specific countries. I can generate a map with square grids just fine, but I'm running into problems getting the `cellsize` argument in `st_make_grid()` to use sensible metrics.

I understand that I want the maps to use the same projection, and given the units I want one that's using meters. I've checked this repeatedly using `st_crs()` and it indicates all of the objects are using meters as intended.

This first chunk of code lists the countries I want to include, and lists the CRS code I want to use. I convert each of the three maps returned by `gadm()` to sf objections, combine the data frames, and apply the CRS code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geodata)

countrylist <- list("DEU", "FRA", "GBR")
wgseqproj <- "EPSG:4087"

tempmap <- countrylist |>
    map(~ gadm(country = .x, level = 0, path = here::here())) |>
    map_dfr(~ st_as_sf(.x)) |>
    sf::st_set_crs(wgseqproj) |>
    sf::st_transform(wgseqproj)
```

The next chunk of code takes the grid and limits it to the borders of the countries in the list. I take the map from above, make the grid, and use `st_intersection()` to limit the grid to the country borders. The last line just creates a numeric index for each box in the grid.

```
  tempgrid <- st_make_grid(tempmap, cellsize = c(0.5, 0.5), square = TRUE, crs = wgseqproj) |> # grid of points
    st_intersection(tempmap) |>
    st_as_sf() |>
    mutate(names = seq(n():1))

ggplot(tempgrid) + geom_sf()
```

[Map resulting from code chunks above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzEBw.png)

The code runs fine, and the resulting image looks normal, but the `cellsize = c(0.5, 0.5)` is the section where I'm running into problems. The maps are in meters, but I don't know what this is capturing (i.e. what does 0.5 translate to?). When I try to run something like `cellsize = c(50000, 50000)` to get 50km square grids the resulting grids are so large they take up the entire map and I just get country border outlines.

Other code I see uses similarly "large" numbers and the results look great. Is it something about the projection or the gadm maps that's throwing this off? When when I run more stripped down code on a single country and get rid of the `map()` functions to simplify things I get the same strange results. I've also tried multiple CRS codes. Any helps is much appreciated!

Comment: If you check the x and y axes, the co-ordinates are not correct. What if you remove `st_set_crs`?

Comment: Yes! I think that fixed it! I had been getting errors in building the pipeline about trying to transform a crs where a origin crs didn't exist, so I was trying to make sure the base maps had specific crs values assigned, but this remnant looks like the source of the error. I had noticed the coordinates were wonky, too, but wasn't sure why. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are overwriting the correct crs with `st_set_crs`. Instead, try:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geodata)
library(sf)

countrylist <- list("DEU", "FRA", "GBR")
wgseqproj <- "EPSG:4087"

tempmap <- countrylist |>
  map(~ gadm(country = .x, level = 0, path = here::here())) |>
  map_dfr(~ st_as_sf(.x)) |>
  sf::st_transform(wgseqproj)

tempgrid <- st_make_grid(tempmap, cellsize = 50000, 
                         square = TRUE, crs = wgseqproj) |> 
  st_intersection(tempmap) |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  mutate(names = seq(n():1))

ggplot(tempgrid) + geom_sf()
```

[image]